# Negative values in launch file arguments

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

`roslaunch` can't read negative argument.

I'm launching my node via this launch file:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="inc" default="-0.02"/>
    <node pkg="parameter_analyzer" type="kld_err" name="parameter_analyzer" output="screen">
        <param name="increment" value="$(arg inc)"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

Output:

```
[ INFO] [1461752716.797017994, 13371.605000000]:  INCREMENT VALUE: 0
```

If parameter is set to positive, output:

```
[ INFO] [1461752338.872513841, 13012.430000000]: INCREMENT VALUE: 0.02
```

**Any suggestions? Thanks.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233019/negative-values-in-launch-file-arguments/) by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 856 on 2016-04-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-04-27**:
It works for me in both hydro and indigo. Could you check your code that you are not doing something wrong while retrieving the parameter?

**Comment by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) on 2016-04-27**:
kindly also post the line from your source file where you are loading this param.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-27**:
My roslaunch's version is `1.11.19` in indigo. And there is only  3  lines: `double INC;` and `ros::param::get("parameter_analyzer/increment", INC);` and `ROS_INFO("INCREMENT VALUE: %lf", INC);`

**Comment by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) on 2016-04-27**:
By using `ros::param::get()` I am also recieving 0 (very small value in exponent). Using:

`ros::NodeHandle n("~");   double increment;   n.param<double>("increment", increment, 5.0);`

you can receive negative values.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-27**:
Thanks! I'm trying, Please write as answer to let me marking correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Alright, so the problem is most probably in [this line of your code](https://github.com/orhangazi44/parameter_analyzer/blob/master/cfg/analyzer.cfg#L14).

You use `dynamic_reconfigure` for your parameters, and you limit the `increment` param to the range [0.0, 500].
Thus, setting to positive should work, but not to negative. However, I'm not quite sure how `dynamic_reconfigure` reacts to parameters being not properly set from the outside...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your launch file:

```
<launch>
<arg name="inc" default="-0.02"/>
<node pkg="parameter_analyzer" type="kld_err" name="parameter_analyzer" output="screen">
    <param name="increment" type="double" value="$(arg inc)"/>
</node>
```

In your source file, use:

```
 ros::NodeHandle nodehandle("~");
 double INC = 0.0;
 nodehandle.param<double>("parameter_analyzer/increment", INC, INC);
```

make sure to pass default value as 3rd argument to `param()` (I'm not sure for what reason If I don't pass this a double/float value here, it gives me 0)

---

Originally posted by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) with karma: 161 on 2016-04-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-27**:
I've just tried. Sorry, but I think the problem isn't caused by getting parameter. Because I'm setting manually via `rosparam set /parameter_analyzer -0.07` but the value in parameter server changes to `0.0` when I launching the node via `roslaunch`.

**Comment by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) on 2016-04-27**:
your parameter should be `/parameter_analyzer/increment`

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-04-27**:
This is due to the fact that when you roslaunch the launch file, the argument specified therein is still set as the parameter. You need to commount the `param` line in the launch file to take the parameter which is already on the parameter server.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-27**:
Thanks for an answers. I've tried `/parameter_analyzer/increment` before too. And commenting increment values in launch file isn't helped. I've setted manually to `-0.7` and started commented-launch-file, it gave `0.0` too.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-27**:
It's getting positive values succesfully. Why? :) I'm really confused.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-04-27**:
There must be something wrong with your code then. Please post the full code in question, otherwise it is almost impossible to debug.

Check out https://github.com/ipa-mig/ros_sandbox/tree/test there is an example python and cpp package where this works...

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-27**:
Thank you very much for your code. I've just executed `rosrun cpp_test cpp_test_node`  (tried roslaunch before). It doesn't output's anything. I also looked to code, It must be write something. Now I'm trying on different computer.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-27**:
I accidentally clonned master branch before, It runs succesfully and gets parameter. And I've just uploaded code to [repo](https://github.com/orhangazi44/parameter_analyzer.git). I'm running node via `roslaunch parameter_analyzer laser_lambda_short.launch`.

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-04-27**:
Other nodes hasn't got `ROS_INFO()` line for looking parameter without launching amcl.